# Obtener datos a partir de una expresion regular

Tags: regex

Tengo un problema al tratar de averiguar cuál es mi usuario y contraseña.

Tengo un desafío que hacer y me piden que encuentre mi usuario y contraseña basado en una pista dada por la siguiente expresión regular:

```
[1-3]{0,4}
```

Lo cual me da un número de intendidad que creo que sirve como pista también para poder determinar la respuesta:

```
2035645013
```

He buscado pero no encuentro nada que me podría ayudar.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresión:

```
[1-3]{0,4}
```

Quiere decir: una sucesión de entre ningún y 4 números, todos ellos entre el 1 y 3.

Esto quiere decir que los siguientes valores lo cumplen:

```
  # nada
1
123
111
1111
```

etcétera.

Ahora, dado:

```
2035645013
```

Debemos ir explorando qué combinaciones lo tienen:

```
2035645013
^       ^^
```

Mirándolo bien, observamos que solamente hay dos secuencias posibles:

```
2     # números entre 1 y 3, 1 vez
13    # números entre 1 y 3, 2 veces
```

Por tanto la solución es que es o bien **2** o bien **13**. ¿Tal vez el nombre de usuario es 2 y la contraseña 13?

Answer (score 1):

Pues al aplicarle esa expresión regular al numero que te han dado, obtienes:

> 2313

y los números sobrantes son:

> 056450

Comment: Deben ser consecutivos. Lo único que estás haciendo aquí es eliminar los que salen del rango [1-3].